# In Epplus Convert String Date as Date in Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, excel, epplus

I am dumping a string Date from DataTable to Epplus. I want to treat that date as Date in Excel. So that I can get Date Filter in Excel.

Things I tried,

- Passed that date as Datetime. Now, Excel takes it as date and gets a date filter. But, it affects the pivot
- Passed it as string with req. date format, The excel takes it as string and does not gets the date Filter in excel.

Hope i will get a solution from you guys. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Numberformat` property.

If you want set for whole column then you can apply it following way

```
ws.Column(1).Style.Numberformat.Format  = "yyyy-MM-dd";
```

Or for particular cell

```
ws.Cells["A3"].Style.Numberformat.Format = "yyyy-MM-dd";
```